# Pivoteo de un DataFrame completo, Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Lo primero muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Mi pregunta es sobre un *DataFrame* con esta estructura:

```
Fecha   Resonancias Radiologías Tomografías Ecografías  Densitometrías  Mamografías
1-24    28             54          8          0.0         0.0                0.0
1-23    27             45         39         25.0         0.0                0.0
1-19    25             150        31         44.0         4.0                8.0
1-27    24             125         5         48.0         1.0                8.0
1-25    24             117        22         45.0         3.0                6.0
```

¿Cómo puedo pivotear la tabla/DataFrame para que salga justo al revés respetando los valores?

```
                  1-18    1-19    1-20   ...    ...    ...    ...  ...
   Resonancias      28      27      25
   Radiologías      54      45     150
   Tomografías      ...    ...     ...
    ...
    ...
```

He probado con pivot, pero como el índice es "Fecha" no me coge la columna (KeyError), al poner un índice automático me la coge, pero no consigo un resultado parecido a lo que quiero , quizás con pivot_table pero no quiero hacer medias, ni sumas, ni operar con los datos únicamente mostrarlos como están.

¿Se puede hacer sin  crear un *DataFrame* nuevo?

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Israel, que facil y las vueltas que he dado! . Tendré que fijarme mas en la documentación. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba utilizando `transpose(*args, copy=False)`, dejo [aquí la documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas-dataframe-transpose) que dice lo siguiente:

> Refleje el DataFrame sobre su diagonal principal escribiendo filas como columnas y viceversa. La propiedad **T** es un acceso al método transpose().

Dejo el ejemplo para que veas como podrías hacerlo:

```
d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

Imprimiendo la variable `df1` obtendrías un resultado de la siguiente forma:

> ```
>    col1  col2
> 0     1     3
> 1     2     4
> ```

Ahora usamos *transpose*:

```
df1_transposed = df1.T # or df1.transpose()
```

Dándonos un resultado de la siguiente forma:

> ```
>       0  1
> col1  1  2
> col2  3  4
> ```

El ejemplo original puedes encontrarlo en la documentación la cual puse el link anteriormente.

Espero te funcione. Saludos ;)